# How to get CPU usage in C program with percentage %

Tags: c, linux, cpu-usage

I try to get a cpu usage with c program but the result does not come out in percentage %, what is wrong with this code? Maybe someone can clarify or offer me another way to recover the CPU used.

My code :

```c
 int GetCPULoad() {
    int FileHandler;
    char FileBuffer[1024];
    float load;

    FileHandler = open("/proc/loadavg", O_RDONLY);
    if(FileHandler < 0) {
        return -1; }
    read(FileHandler, FileBuffer, sizeof(FileBuffer) - 1);
    sscanf(FileBuffer, "%f", &load);
    close(FileHandler);
    return (int)(load * 100);
}
```

maybe can i do that with /proc/stat file, any one know how to do that ?

i have try another code

```
    fp = fopen ("/proc/stat", "r");
    if (fp) {
    long long unsigned int user,nice,system,idle;
    int i = fscanf(fp,"%*s %llu %llu %llu %llu",&user,&nice,&system,&idle);
    int total_cpu_usage1;
    total_cpu_usage1 = user + nice + system + idle;
    sprintf( http_buf,"<br>CPU usage: %d ", total_cpu_usage1); tcp_write(&tcpbuf, sock, http_buf, strlen(http_buf) );
    fclose(fp);
    }
```

but same result : CPU usage: 159838295

how can i get the persentage % ?

Comment: Why are you putting comparisons in the increment part of the `for` loop? That doesn't change the repeat condition `i <= 10`

Comment: The easiest way is with multiple loops that have different conditions.

Comment: Better and more consistent formatting would make your code easier to read, btw. That `if` statement should be split up into lines, and you spaces after some opening parens and not others....

Comment: sorry i have remove c++ language

Comment: how can i create multiple loops with different condition ?  i canot use something like this : for (i=1; i<=10; i++ || i==20 || i==30) {                      on same loop ?

Comment: Just do multple `for` loops, and use `i++` or `i += 10` or `i += 30` as the final part to increment by different amounts.

Comment: I can't believe I need to spell that out, it seems obvious.

Comment: It seems like you don't understand how `for` works if you think that's even close to right.

Comment: Or you don't understand what `||` does.

Comment: Putting `i == 20` in the increment part doesn't change the `i <= 10` condition that stops the loop when you get to 10.

Comment: It seems like you're just combining operators randomly, without really thinking about what they do. What part of any of that *adds* 10 to `i`?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be with multiple loops that have different ranges and different increments.

```
for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    ...
}
for (i = 10; i <= 30; i += 10) {
    ...
}
for (i = 60; i <= 120; i += 30) {
    ...
}
```

If you really have to do it in a single loop:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 120; 
        i = i < 10 ? i + 1 : 
                     (i < 30 ? i + 10 : i + 30))
```

The last part of the `for` loop header increments `i` by different values depending on the range it's in.

Comment: you are a genius , thank you verry much  its work

Comment: mr barmar , its possible to have your contact ?

Comment: No, I don't provide private consulting, I just answer in SO.

Comment: i can not add new question , and i need help for : how to get CPU usage in c programe, i aready post a question but stackoverflow have delet it cause i dont give more explications , but i dont have more explication :( , its possible to have answer of how to get the  cpu usage on this question ?.

Comment: Use the `getrusage()` function on Linux.

Comment: i have find no exemple with getrusage()